# Creating and sending a newsletter

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, email, newsletter

I'd like to add a newsletter feature to my project to send constructed mails to all subscribed users.  Although I'm not expecting high volume at all, I'd like to make this with a view to reusing it for projects in which the volume of mails being sent, could be large.  However, I am confused as to what strategy I can use for this.  To quote the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133906/send-newsletter-in-asp-net-to-around-10000-emails):

> I would not recommend asp.net webpage to send, even if you do start it in a separate background
>   thread. I would think you run the risk of the server recycling your process in the middle of the
>   send, which would mess it up. You really need to write some kind of separate service or
>   application to send your emails.

This implies a WCF service would be the way to go, but does it matter whether it's an OData or RIA service?  The MSDN documentation is a little confusing as to what each type is for.  It gives Silverlight as an example to use RIA, but still says you can use it independently too.

Also, even if I do use a service this way, does the above quote about recycling the process mean I wouldn't be able to call it from an MVC controller, as it would recycle the process whilst the controller is waiting for the service anyway?  Ideally, I'd like to create the mail with MVC, pass that onto the service, send the mails and process the results within MVC itself.

The last problem after that is whether I can implement forms authentication with the service.  I'd need to be able to control access to the service so that other people can't randomly send newsletters.

Are these goals achievable with WCF and MVC combined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing something similar, and bearing in mind I want to guarantee everything is sent. I just set up the contents of the message in my controller, and then write the message and list of recipients (or in this case a filter that defines the recipients) into a database.

Then I have an entirely separate process running outside of ASP (a Windows service in my case) which periodically checks the database for send requests, sends them, and flags them as sent.

Obviously the MVC controller takes care of all the authentication issues.  Once a send request is logged in the database it is assumed to be fully authorised.

You could do a similar thing by communicating between ASP and the Windows service using WCF, but I think it's overly complex.  It's harder to guarantee the request is eventually handled. You really need a database record to be 100% certain of this anyway - so that record might as well be your message.  You also don't generally need real time triggering of the email send.

Comment: Thanks for the answer James.  That makes things far easier to work with.